# custom dropdownlist html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a custom control used in web application,I want to create html helper for an MVC helper using the logic of this custom control

Here's the code for the web application that I want to convert :

```
 [ToolboxData("<{0}:CustDropDownList runat=server></{0}:CustDropDownList>")]
public class CustDropDownList : System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList
{
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        var strDivAttributes = this.Enabled ? "select-box" : "select-box disabled";
        writer.Write("<div id=\"{0}Div\" class=\"{1}\">", this.ClientID, strDivAttributes);
        base.Render(writer);
        writer.Write("</div>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extension method to the HtmlHelper class like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustDropDownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    // ... your custom logic goes here
    return new MvcHtmlString.Create("<div>some HTML...</div>");
}
```

You can then call it from a view like so:

```
@Html.CustDropDownList()
```

EDIT
If you want to use this for a model property you'll need a something like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustDropDownListFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    // ... your custom logic goes here
    return new MvcHtmlString.Create("<div>some HTML...</div>");
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
@Html.CustDropDownListFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
```